# Syntax Error The source line is 1

Tags: linux, bash, unix, redirect, scripting

I have a server list in hostlist file and I am trying to execute below script:

```
!/bin/bash
for server in cat hostlist; do ssh $server 'hostname ;id $(cat /etc/passwd | grep Luyang | awk -F '[:]' '{print $1}') ; id ppandey' >> b done
```

I want to fetch outputs for id command of user Luyang. For the same I have mentioned `id $(cat /etc/passwd | grep Luyang | awk -F '[:]' '{print $1}')` but I am getting errors while running the script. I also tried to put '\' in front of all special characters but no luck.

Comment: Do you have `!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/bash`? You must have the 2nd. You also appear to be missing a semi-colon before `done`. Please format your post better: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: `cat|grep|awk` is an *antipattern*. A single awk is enough.

Comment: @Jens Thats the least of their problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems here:

- The first line needs a `#` to be a proper shebang line (i.e. `#!/bin/bash`).
- `for server in cat hostlist` will run the loop twice, once with $server set to "cat", then with it set to "hostlist". You want to execute `cat hostlist` as a command and use its output, i.e. `for server in $(cat hostlist)`.

  Actually, depending on the exact format and content of the file, `while read -u3 server; do ... done 3<hostfile` might be better, but the `for` version is probably good enough here. (The differences are that `for` breaks the file into words, not lines, and expands any wildcards as if they were filenames. I wouldn't expect either to matter here.)
- You can't nest quotes the way you're trying to. When you have a single-quoted string like `'hostname ;id ... ; id ppandey'`, any single-quotes in the middle are taken as ending the single-quoted string, not as part of it. I'd switch to using double-quotes for the outer set, and then escaping the `$`s inside to keep them from being interpreted.
- `cat|grep|awk` is overcomplicated, since `awk` can read directly from files and search all by itself. Just use `awk -F : '/Luyang/ {print $1}' /etc/passwd`.
- You need a semicolon or line break before `done`. Personally, I think breaking loops into logical lines makes them easier to read, so I'd go with that.
- Finally, you might want to use absolute paths for the files hostlist and b. As it is, it'll look in the working directory of whatever process launched the script, which could be anything. You should *not* assume it's the directory the script is in.

Here's what I get overall (except for absolute paths). Note that I also double-quoted `"$server"`, just on general principles.

```
#!/bin/bash
for server in $(cat hostlist); do
    ssh "$server" "hostname; id \$(awk -F : '/Luyang/ {print \$1}' /etc/passwd); id ppandey" >> b
done
```

Answer (score -2):

Just enclose your cat command between $() and ; after the append command.

```
!/bin/bash
for server in $(cat hostlist); do ssh $server 'hostname ;id $(cat /etc/passwd | grep Luyang | awk -F '[:]' '{print $1}') ; id ppandey' >> b; done
```

Comment: Even if that solves the immediate problem, that's not the correct way to iterate over the contents of a file.

Comment: But please do enlighten us on the correct way because I see it used in the answer above as well. Also, I don't see the point in the -2 given for an answer that actually works.